# Sage pay Form Protocol update from 2.23 to 3.00

Tags: php, forms, opayo

I am currently trying to make update sage pay Form Protocol from 2.23 to 3.00.

From documentation I can read that only change is protocol value from 2.23 to 3.00 but when I've changed this after login on to sagepay website it still say that we are using old 2.23 protocol and needs to upgrade to 3.0.

Payments are working OK, protocol value is 3.00 but it still asking for upgrade to 3.00.

We are not going to use any of new features.

We currently use AES.

Can someone help?

Comment: I think this was a temporary bug in My Sage Pay. If you are using protocol 3.00 and AES for your form transactions, you needn't worry.

Comment: This is my experience having done likewise today. If it's a bug it should be fixed because the [documentation](https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-integration-document/migrate-to-v3) says we should use this banner to determine which version is in use; it's clearly not working.